# Azure DevOps Repository to update Azure DevOps Boards

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-repos, azure-boards

In the past I used to use GitHub to store my repositories. I had a hook in GitHub set up for Pivotal Tracker that would allow me to pass an id and a status and it would update the job in Pivotal Tracker when the commit was made.

I would like to do the same thing when committing work into my Azure DevOps repository. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Boards has native integration with Repos. Simply use `#123` where `123` is the Work Item ID to link the work to the work item.

You can also link work items to branches.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/connect-work-items-to-git-dev-ops?view=azure-devops

---

### or you can go nuts and build your own integration.

You can create a Service Hook in Azure DevOps and (with an optional Azure Function or Microsoft Flow connection, you can make it do just about anything. Triggering the event is detailed below. Creating the Azure Function or Microsoft Flow workflow (or anything else that can process the event and translate it to what Pivotal understands) is up to you.

[image]

Then

[image]

And finally:

[image]
See:

- [Create Service Hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops)
- [Flow & Azure DevOps](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/shared_visualstudioteamservices/azure-devops/)

Comment: With the first method, can you close a story? Or should I set up the integration instead?

Comment: The GitHub integration does that... Not yet on Azure Repos, but in may be an option to wait, as this feature is being added at the moment (planned for 2019/Q3: https://dev.azure.com/mseng/AzureDevOpsRoadmap/_workitems/edit/1553151